# Multiple Sprite Actions

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I am using Cocos2d engine and I've faced a strange problem.

I have a sprite. Also, I have 2 animations for that sprite. And I want to play one animation when app loads and second, after ccTouchevent is called.

```
walkAnim = [CCAnimation animation]; 
dropAnim = [CCAnimation animation]; 
for( int q=1;q<12;q++){
    [walkAnim addFrameWithFilename: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"walkforward_%.2d.png", q]];
    [dropAnim addFrameWithFilename: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"drop_%.2d.png", q]];
}
action = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:walkAnim];
action.duration = 2;
id act = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:action];
[sprite runAction:act];
```

So, here we see an animating sprite.

```
[sprite stopAllActions]; //and here my torture begins
```

I have tried many ways of creating an action:
I've tried to add another AnimateAction, tried to replace the current animation, but everything results in a crash.

```
[action setAnimation:dropAnim];
```

and

```
CCAnimate* animat = [[CCAnimate alloc]initWithDuration:30 animation:dropAnim restoreOriginalFrame:YES];
```

and

```
id action = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:dropAnim]];
[player1 runAction:action];
```

The crash is in [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:]

```
+(id) actionWithAnimation: (CCAnimation*)anim
{    
    return [[[self alloc] initWithAnimation:anim restoreOriginalFrame:YES] autorelease];
}
```

Thanks!

**To launch an action from another method, you have to retain the action 
Eg: [action retain];**

Comment: if you have found an answer for your question, please answer yourself here and accept it, so other can use it in case they found this post. Good luck!

Comment: Note the "and accept it" part, URLArenzo. Also, please consider your tags more carefully. This has nothing at all to do with Xcode 4 - it's a language/API problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To launch an action from another method, you have to retain the action 

Eg: [action retain]; and then do not forget to release it**

```
-(void)create{
    for( int q=1;q<12;q++){
        [playerWalkAnim addFrameWithFilename: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"walkforward_%.2d.png", q]];
    }
    playerAction = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:playerWalkAnim];
    playerAction.duration = 2;

    [playerAction retain];
}

-(void)launch{
    [player1 runAction:playerAction];
}
```